# Django SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN error

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to using `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN`, but I get an error in *any* browser I try when I try to log into the admin:

```
Looks like your browser isn't configured to accept cookies. Please enable cookies, reload this page, and try again.
```

Any idea?

Comment: Does the problem disappear when you remove cookies for that domain maually? Or when you restart django server?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you might want to look into is the setting `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE`.  If it's set to `True` make sure you are using https.  Otherwise, set it to `False` and use http.

Answer (score 0):

This usually indicates that you have misconfigured your SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN setting. Can you provide more info?

What domain are you running your app on? 
What is the current value of SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN?

Answer (score 0):

In certain circumstances, server-side caching may be the culprit here. We use Varnish to create cache on certain high-traffic sites, and found that it interferes with CSRF validation. The version of the CSRF token that is served from cache will likely be invalid if the cache is more than a few seconds old.

You may need to disable server-side caching for login forms (/admin, for example) and other places where CSRF is used.